# Makefile not building when updating source

Tags: c, makefile

I've recently picked up makefiles and am trying to automate my build process. For this makefile, I want it to find every xxx/src/xxx.c source file and build an equivalent xxx/obj/xxx.o object for each. So every obj folder mirrors the layout of a src folder.

This is working as intended but only if I clean and make. Modifying a source file and running make won't rebuild that file. I think it might have to do with my subst in the dependecy of %.o, but I don't know how to modify that and still have my automated build layout work.

```
CFLAGS := -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O3
LIBARIES := -lm -lglut -lGL

INCDIR := include ../plib/include
SRCDIR := src ../plib/src

INC := $(foreach d, $(INCDIR),-I$d)
SRC := $(wildcard $(foreach d, $(SRCDIR),$d/*.c $d/*/*.c))
OBJ := $(subst src/,obj/, $(SRC:.c=.o))
EXE := bin/test

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBARIES)
    $@

%.o: $(subst obj/,src/,$(%.c))
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    gcc -o $@ -c $(subst obj/,src/,$(@:.o=.c)) $(CFLAGS) $(INC)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm $(EXE)
    rm $(OBJ)
```

Comment: Is it correctly detecting your `.c` files?

Comment: Where did `$(%.c)` come from?  That means, _expand the variable with the literal name `%.c`_.  Since you've never defined a variable named `%.c`, it expands to the empty string.  So, your object file has no prerequisites, and so as long as it exists it can never be out of date and will never be rebuilt.

Comment: If you insist on having the `obj` directories embedded in each subdirectory you will have some pain in implementing this.  You will need to create a separate pattern rule for every source directory.  If you're willing to use a single top-level `obj` directory instead (e.g., instead of `xxx/obj/xxx.o` you're willing to use `obj/xxx/src/xxx.o` then it's very simple to do.

Comment: @tadman It is correctly detecting them. Making works, just only if I clean first.

Comment: @MadScientist Could you tell me how I implement something like that? I'm not too picky with how everything in the obj folder is laid out. I just want all my objects to be in there.

Comment: Does it work if rules are explicitly entered for source files?  There could be another problem at play here, such as use of a network filesystem with clocks that are out-of-sync.

Comment: Once Make sees the rule that a .o depends on a .c, it should be checking for file changes. IIRC (been a while) `make -p` will show the effective rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve such a `%/xxxx/%` pattern replacement by iterating over the `SRCDIR`:

```
define genrule
_prefix := $$(subst src,obj,$1/)
$$(filter $${_prefix}%.o,$$(OBJ)):\
$${_prefix}%.o: $1/%.c
endef

$(foreach d,${SRCDIR},$(eval $(call genrule,$d)))

${OBJ}:
          gcc ... -c $< -p $@
```

Comment: Okay, I added your rule and called it just before the $(OBJ) rule, and clean+make works. But modifying a source file and running make does not. I don't know what to put in the dependencies for your $(OBJ) rule. If I put $(SRC) then it recompiles all files even if only one is modified.

Comment: I updated the script; `$<` works only when `genrule` creates an explicit rule and there was typo (`src` and `obj` were swapped).

Comment: Wait, this works wonderfully now! The objects are in the right places and it's rebuilding when modifying source files. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion). It's not elegant, but it works:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(addsuffix .c,$$(basename $$(subst /obj/,/src/,$$@)))
    @echo building $@ from $^
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    gcc -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(INC)
```

Comment: This looks like what I want but I it threw me the error "No rule to make target `obj/main.o', needed by `bin/test'." so I'm assuming the dependency didn't expand properly. I think secondary expansion is a Make 3.82 addition that's not available for many people even after manually updating make.

Answer (score 1):

The posted makefile is rather 'iffy' for several different reasons

The following proposed makefile is VERY EASILY modified for other projects BUT does place the object files in the same directory as the source files.  You might want to 'tweak' that feature

And now, the proposed makefile

```
SHELL   :=  /bin/sh
CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc
RM      :=  /usr/bin/rm
MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CFLAGS := -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O3
LIBS   := -lm -lglut -lGL

INC :=   -Iinclude/ -I../plib/
SRC :=   $(wildcard src/*.c)  $(wildcard ../plib/src/*.c)
OBJ :=   $(SRC:.c=.o))
DEP :=   $(SRC:.c=.d)
EXE :=   bin/test

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    #
    # ======= $(EXE) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(EXE) Link Done ==========
    #


#
# create dependancy files
#
%.d: %.c
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    (RM) -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========

#
# compile the .c files into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INC)
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 


clean: 
    # ========== start clean activities ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(EXE)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== end clean activities ==========


# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to improve my makefile so much! Unfortunately, it throws me the error "/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected" when I run it.

Comment: Does it throw that error when first starting or later in the processing?  In any case, the `SHELL` statement is to tell `make` which shell to use.  If the line is not in the makefile, then `make` will use the default shell

Comment: It throws it later in the processing. I pasted your code verbatim, making sure to swap the spaces for indentation so make would accept it.

Comment: there are a lot of command line options that can be passed to `make`.  One of them is `-d`  so `make` will output a LOT of debug information.  If you use that option, then you can tell exactly where a problem is occurring in the makefile

Comment: Note: in the `clean` recipe, the `rm` should be replaced with `$(RM)`  Sorry, my oversight

Comment: for future reference, the [gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf) contains all the details for using `make`

Comment: Okay, I will keep this in mind for when I'm debugging any future makefiles! I appreciate the work that went into developing this solution but the accepted answer works fine without generating any dependency files.